# What does ddx (hlsl) actually do?

Tags: hlsl

I'm a bit confused.  The official documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509588(v=vs.85).aspx) says that ddx(input) is the partial derivative of the input with respect to the "screen-space x-coordinate."

My calculus is fine, but how can it tell what the input is coming from?  If I passed it a function, fine, I can imagine what it would do, but the derivative of a number is always zero...?

Is it just a scaling?  Like, this would get scaled to one tenth of its size at this distance, so it returns one tenth?  But then it doesn't need an input...

Can someone give a quick explanation of what's actually happening?

Comment: `ddx` and `ddy` do magic that you cannot do yourself.  They have access to additional information from the rasterization pipeline that you can't acquire from within a pixel shader.  I'm unsure exactly which formula they use; I've been led to believe they use an estimation technique, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: That's deeply weird, but still.  What does ddx(5) actually represent?  If it says .1, how should I interpret that?  Or -6?

Comment: `ddx(5)` is kind of pointless.  Use it with an input value, and that will give you the derivative of that value with respect to neighboring pixels in a block.  Again, I don't know how precisely it calculates values, but asking for the derivative of a non-input may well just be undefined behavior and produce garbage.  See http://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/07/10/a-trip-through-the-graphics-pipeline-2011-part-8/ for more information than I can provide.

Comment: I am not sure but it might well be that the HLSL compiler is actually doing full symbolic differentiation of the expression that you pass to the ddx/ddy. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2011/03/08/hlsl-compiler-support-for-symbolic-derivatives.aspx http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/146019/SymbolicDifferentiationInGPUShadersTechReport.pdf

Comment: What does it do? The ***ONLY*** slightly reasonable thing, obviously.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Internally, GPUs never run one instance of a pixel shader at a time.  At the finest level of granularity, they are always running 32-64 pixels at the same time using a SIMD architecture.  Within this, the pixels are further organized into 2x2 quads, so each group of 4 consecutive pixels in the SIMD vector corresponds to a 2x2 block of pixels on screen.

Derivatives are calculated by taking differences between the pixels in a quad.  For instance, `ddx` will subtract the values in the pixels on the left side of the quad from the values on the right side, and `ddy` will subtract the bottom pixels from the top ones.  The differences can then be returned as the derivative to all four pixels in the quad.

Since the pixel shader is running in SIMD, it's guaranteed that the corresponding value is in the same register at the same time for all the pixels in the quad.  So whatever expression or value you put into `ddx` or `ddy`, it will be evaluated in all four pixels of the quad, then the values from different pixels subtracted as described above.

So taking the derivative of a constant value will give zero (as you'd expect from calculus, right?) because it's the same constant value in all four pixels.

Also note that there are "coarse" and "fine" derivatives, `ddx_coarse`/`ddy_coarse` and `ddx_fine`/`ddy_fine`.  An explanation of the distinction is given [here](http://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/07/10/a-trip-through-the-graphics-pipeline-2011-part-8/#comment-1990).  Just plain `ddx`/`ddy` are aliases for the coarse versions.

BTW, the reason this functionality exists is that GPUs internally have to take derivatives of texture coordinates in order to do mipmap selection and anisotropic filtering.  Since the hardware needs the capability anyway (you can use any arbitrary expression for texture coordinates in a shader), it was easy enough to also expose it to shader programmers directly.

Comment: +1; I've found this useful when applying a perturbation effect to a texture; the perturbed texcoords gave some colour distortion, but using tex2Dgrad with derivatives from the original (unperturbed) texcoords gave an undistorted result.

Comment: Alright, after some thought I think I figured out my confusion.  In my mind, `ddx` works like every other function in a traditional programming language; you evaluate the input, turn it to a float or whatever, then do the outside function (`ddx`) to it.  But this is different- it takes the input *string*, evaluates it in several places, calculates a derivative, and reports the result.  Is that about right?

Comment: @RichardRast Right. You can think of `ddx` as operating on the *expression* you pass into it, rather than the *value*.

Comment: But see, that's weird enough that it should be in the documentation.  I can think of no other time in my programming life where that has been the case.

Comment: Nathan Reed mentioned that GPUs use these functions for mipmap selection.  You can also use them to force the GPU to select a desired mipmap level or to prevent artifacts from incorrect mip-level selection.  The process is described on pages 163 and 164 of Shader X3.

Comment: Bump Mapping uses ddx (the partial derivative) to perturb normals, see http://jbit.net/%7Esparky/sfgrad_bump/mm_sfgrad_bump.pdf