# Why do you use logarithmic curve to fix distortion of texture?

Tags: unity, shaders, hlsl

I'm a noob shader learner, and I came across this question about animated shaders in Unity: [Animated textures for models; How to write a shader?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/135375/animated-textures-for-models-how-to-write-a-shader)

After reading the answer, I kind of understood the concept of using polar coordinate to animate circular movement of texture. What I failed to comprehend was how the `log()` function reduces the distortion of texture. So my question, is how does `log` help the image scale up linearly (not sure if it's the right terminology)?

Here's the shader code from the link just in case.

```
fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
{
    float2 polar = float2(
           atan2(i.uv.y, i.uv.x) / (2.0f * 3.141592653589f), // angle
           log(dot(i.uv, i.uv)) * 0.5f                       // log-radius
        );

    // Check how much our texture sampling point changes between
    // neighbouring pixels to the sides (ddx) and above/below (ddy)
    float4 gradient = float4(ddx(polar), ddy(polar));

    // If our angle wraps around between adjacent samples,
    // discard one full rotation from its value and keep the fraction.
    gradient.xz = frac(gradient.xz + 1.5f) - 0.5f;

    // Copy the polar coordinates before we scale & shift them,
    // so we can scale & shift the tint texture independently.
    float2 tintUVs = polar * _TintTex_ST.xy;
    tintUVs += _ScrollSpeeds.zw * _Time.x;

    polar *= _MainTex_ST.xy;
    polar += _ScrollSpeeds.xy * _Time.x;

    // Sample with our custom gradients.
    fixed4 col = tex2Dgrad(_MainTex, polar, 
                           _MainTex_ST.xy * gradient.xy,
                           _MainTex_ST.xy * gradient.zw
                         );

    // Since our tint texture has its own scale,
    // its gradients also need to be scaled to match.
    col *= tex2Dgrad(_TintTex, tintUVs,
                          _TintTex_ST.xy * gradient.xy,
                          _TintTex_ST.xy * gradient.zw
                         );

    UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, col);
    return col;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comes from trying to make each tile of the image maintain the same width:height aspect ratio as we reduce in size toward the center of the funnel.

Let's take a swatch of this endless pattern, and look at one ring of texture repeats where the top of the tiles sits exactly on the unit circle (in yellow):

[image: Example tiling]

A single tile in this ring has a width \$w\$ along its curved top edge, and a radial height \$h\$. Its bottom edge is shorter, because the image tapers in toward the center - let's express it as some fraction of the top width we'll call \$a\$.

Now we want to ask, how big is the next tile down the funnel? Well, we know its top width is \$aw\$, since its top is the previous tile's bottom. That means, if we want to maintain the same aspect ratio as the original tile, the height has to be \$ah\$ (if we multiplied the width by \$a\$, we have to do the same to height to keep it in the same proportion).

By the same argument, we can conclude the third tile down in this stack must be \$a^2w \times a^2h\$, and the one after that \$a^3w \times a^3 h\$

In other words, we have an exponential progression: the height of the \$i^{th}\$ tile down from our unit circle row is \$h_i = a^i h\$.

By a similar argument, we can show the radius at which we'll find the \$i^{th}\$ row of tiles is also an exponential function of the tile number \$i\$.

But in the shader, we want to do the *opposite*: we already know the radius from the center for the pixel being shaded, and we want to figure out which tile that is, to sample the texture at that offset. **So we use the inverse of the exponential function, the logarithm**.

(In the code I showed in my previous answer, I actually take the logarithm of the *square* of the radius, knowing that the logarithm of the square is just twice the logarithm of the original, and halving the answer after the fact is faster than a square root. There are some extra constant factors if you do the full math treatment, but we don't really care about those because they just end up as a scale/shift, and can be subsumed into our texture scaling/scrolling animation anyway)

You'll find this "do the opposite operation" is common when doing texture transformations in a shader, because you're manipulating the function's domain, not its range. So if I want a texture to look twice as big, I halve the uv coordinates. If I want it to be half as big, I double the uv coordinates. If I want the texture to tile exponentially, I adjust the uv coordinates logarithmically.