# Draw a perfect circle in UI

Tags: unity, shaders, unity-shader-graph

[image: Problem example]

This is the problem I have. I have created a shader that draws circle. But depending on the distance from the camera thickness changes.

[image: Circle Shader]

Is it possible to keep thickness constant?

Comment: Did you check out [previous questions about using shaders to draw circles](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/141264/39518)?

Comment: @DMGregory I had a look at them but I am not good with HLSL or GLSL. While I can copy paste some things, I am better at shader graph. I will definitely research more, but for Global Game Jam I don't have too much time to spare. Thanks.

Comment: To use the trick in my answer there in a graph, [you'll need the DDX / DDY nodes described here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ShaderGraph/wiki/Math-Nodes). The technique should translate pretty directly. :)

Comment: @DMGregory Thank you in pointing me in the right direction. I will definitely try to replicate it in Shader Graph and post about my success here.

Comment: Right now I am using Shapes plugin from Freya, works pretty well. It's definitely possible to do it yourself, but requires a lot of knowledge.

Comment: Want to post an answer showing how you solved this with the Shapes library?

Comment: @DMGregory I would if I knew how, I believe I don't understand this topic on acceptable level, I didn't exactly finish this project or done it to have a proof of work. But from examples I could see that it's possible to get satisfactory results - https://acegikmo.com/shapes/docs/#anti-aliasing | Anti-Aliasing chapter. On top of that this is not a free package. Also, if someone is reading this, then there is this post from developers of Kerbal Space Program 2, https://www.kerbalspaceprogram.com/dev-diaries/6509/ , might be useful.