# Why is my blender 2D ring so pixelated when imported into Unity?

Tags: unity, 2d, blender, pixel

I created a simple ring in blender, yet when I import it into Unity it is horribly pixelated and choppy looking.

[image]

I want the ring to look perfectly smooth.

In blender, I selected the "shade smooth" option from the object context menu. It looks smooth in blender, see image here:

[image]

I imported the file into Unity from blender by dragging over the .blend file.

Is blender not a good tool for this?

Comment: Are they the same scale?

Comment: my scale in unity is 0.5 . My game scale is set to 1

Comment: You may be interested in [An Efficient Way to Draw a Smooth Circle](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/141268/39518).