# How to draw a small circle 20px in webgl using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I could use triangles (make them using trigonometry). But the circle I want is small, only 20px diameter.

I could also load a model but I need a quick solution.

Is there an easy method to draw a small circle easily in 3d?

Comment: Instead of 3d, I created the circle in 2d using the arc method.

Comment: If you mean to answer your own question, write it in the "Your Answer" box below, including the code you used. You may also be interested in [An efficient way for generating smooth circle](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/141264/39518).

Comment: @DMGregory thank you