# Efficient unwrapping on multi hard edge object

Tags: uv-mapping, 3d-modeling

I'm having trouble unwrapping this without creating hundreds of seams which massively increases the vertex count in the game engine (Unity).

[image]

I've tried the various projection methods without much success. Three planar maps (45 deg looking down, 45 up and one side) yielded the leat amount but still dozens.

I've tried all sorts of manual seam drawings but can't figure out what would be optimal so I'm looking for suggestions.

Regarding the texture having contiguous seams doesn't really matter.

[Cross posted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124478/efficient-unwrapping-on-multi-hard-edge-object) on Blender Stack Exchange

Comment: This question might receive better answers on https://blender.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The UV seams here may be both inevitable, and not a big deal in practice. When we talk about trying to minimize vertex count, we're usually talking about thousands to millions of vertices, while seams from this object seem like they'd add at most a few hundred extra verts (which might need to split anyway because of differing normals). Do you have profiling figures showing that this object is a major culprit in performance problems in your game?

Comment: @DMGregory I'm coming to the end of finishing the first level of my game so I'm onto graphical optimisation. I still have occlusion culling and some LODs to finish but It's currently clocking around 4M verts on screen most of the time and rendering is a clear bottleneck in the profiler. With that in mind I'm trying to clean up as much as I can. There are only two of these in the scene and yes, I may have to let this one escape the broom but just thought I might be missing some unwrapping technique.

Comment: See also this [previous Q&A that talks about the relative importance of sharing vertices vs other aspects of draw cost](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/148143/39518)