# How can I reduce the size of a png in unity while maintaining picture quality

Tags: unity

I'm new to Unity.  I'm using Unity 2019.1.3f1 Personal.

My issue is that I have created pictures (png) of a character in Photoshop.  The picture borders look clean in Photoshop and looks okay, not the best, when pasted into Unity.  However, the original picture size is too big but when I make it smaller, the picture quality suffers.

I understand that I can make the picture smaller in Photoshop but is that the most efficient way?  If not, how can I resize pictures in Unity and maintain the picture quality?

Below is a side-by-side comparison of the picture after I resize it (left) and before I resize it (right).  Any suggestions is greatly appreciated; thank you for your time,

[image]

Comment: The bilinear/trilinear filtering used to sample scaled textures in realtime, or to auto-generate mipmaps, is not very kind to fine vector lineart. For this reason it's generally recommended to export your sprites to your intended display resolution, rather than scaling them at runtime. If you need to scale vector-style graphics over a wide range of sizes, you may want to consider [signed distance fields](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/169467/39518).

Comment: On top of @DMGregory's comment, it's generally better to have assets in your game that are as close as possible to the desired size, assets takes a large part of a video game, so if all assets were double or triple the size, the game would need more memory without actually needing it.