# Which pixels does the fragment shader of an unlit shader, applied on an object, affect in Unity?

Tags: unity, shaders, fragment-shader

Let's say that I have a cube that has an unlit shader applied to it. The shader does basic ray-marching.

[image]

```
Shader "sdf shader"{
    Properties{
    }
    SubShader{
        Pass{
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            float sphere(float3 posi, float r){
                return distance(posi, unity_ObjectToWorld._m03_m13_m23) - r;
            }

            float4 raymarch(float3 ori, float3 dire, float4 uv, float r){
                float d;
                for(int i; i < 64; i++){
                    if (d > 40){
                        break;
                    }

                    float3 post = ori + (dire * d);

                    if (sphere(post, r) < 0.001){
                        return float4(0,0,0,0);
                    }

                    d += sphere(post, r);
                }
                return uv;
            }

            struct appdata{
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f{
                float4 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };    

            v2f vert (appdata v){
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.vertex;
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target{
                float3 pos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, i.uv);
                float3 dir = normalize(pos - _WorldSpaceCameraPos);
                float4 output = (1,1,1,1);

                float4 col = raymarch(pos, dir, output, 1);
                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Does the shader do calculations for every pixel in the viewport or only the ones covered by the cube? By "covered by the cube", I mean the pixels that are currently displaying the cube and not the area around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fragment shader is invoked for every pixel covered by each non-culled triangle of the mesh being rendered, so long the pixel passes the early depth and stencil tests.

(The early depth test fails if the pixel is occluded behind a closer opaque object that was drawn first, or a closer pixel of the same batch drawn earlier in the draw call if depth writes are enabled. The stencil test only runs if you ask for it, and is used to mask out which regions of the screen can be written to)

If you're ever curious which pixels are getting affected by a shader, or a particular branch in a complex shader program, just write something like `return float4(1, 0, 0, 1);` — any pixel that turns red was running that shader / that branch. Any pixel that doesn't, wasn't.

Technically, the shader also gets invoked for some pixels *just* outside each triangle too: [the graphics card processes 2x2 blocks of pixels at a time](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/130933/39518), so that can include stray pixels wherever the triangle only partially covers such a block. These pixels get masked out, so values outside the triangle don't get written into the destination buffer, so for most purposes we can ignore these invocations — they just contribute to lower shading efficiency when using tons of small triangles where the waste adds up.